# Copying features from one class to another using QGIS modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

How do I copy some features from one class to another in QGIS modeller?

In ArcGIS it was just "Copy features", but I cannot find it in QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @saps! Are you just wanting to copy features from one layer to another (including their attributes)?

Comment: Hello. That is the thing I want to do using QGIS processing modeler.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a **custom script** which allows you to copy features (and attributes) from one layer to another. You can run the script either independently from the *Processing Toolbox* or in your modeler. You can create a script from:

```
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script
```

Then use something like the following:

```
##Copy_features=name
##original_layer=vector
##Copy_to=vector

original_layer = processing.getObject(original_layer)
copy_to_layer = processing.getObject(Copy_to)

feats = [ feat for feat in original_layer.getFeatures() ]

Copy_to_data = copy_to_layer.dataProvider()
attr = original_layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
Copy_to_data.addAttributes(attr)
copy_to_layer.updateFields()
Copy_to_data.addFeatures(feats)
```

Make sure the script is saved in your `/.qgis2/processing/scripts/` directory. Now when you run the script, you can select the original layer and the layer you want to add the copied features to.

Comment: Thank you. So, when copying features is such a big problem in QGIS modeler then wouldn't it be easier to develop whole process as a Python plugin?

Comment: @saps - Most welcome! I don't think the issue is that it's a problem to implement as a tool, it's probably more of a lack of use-case. Doing it manually really only takes a few clicks from the GUI. Saying that, feel free to submit it as a [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis). It could be a future tool :)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem today, but unfortunately, in QGIS 3.2, there is still no such tool. I found that I can use the following method to build a Modeler tool similar to ArcGIS Copy Features tool. But I also think that QGIS can add a standard Copy Features tool.

1. Add a vector layer
2. Add a Select by expression and set the expression to $id > -1
3. Add a Save Selected Features